# selector jquery from $(this).attr

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some checkboxes. When I select one of them I need to add a new element to a list.

I have implemented a change function in jQuery. When I select a checkbox, it adds the element in the list like I want, but when I unselect it, it doesn't remove the element.

The list id is `sumary` and the checkbox and the element in the list have the same attribute `name`.

To remove I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$("#sumary").find("li[name=$(this).attr('name')]").remove();
```

If I hardcode a value for `$(this).attr('name')` it works so the problem is with this:

```
$(this).attr('name')
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't parse variables within strings, so you'll want to concatenate the variable into it. Try:

```
$("#sumary").find("li[name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a matter of fixing your quotes :)

```
$("#sumary").find("li[name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $("#sumary").find("li[name="+$(this).attr('name')+"]").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation to the rescue!

```
$("#sumary").find("li[name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").remove();
```